# Google Domains API "HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method."

Tags: python, api, token, google-workspace

Using the Google Domains API

I am getting this error "HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method."

[image]

And yet I seem to be associating the right files with the right Service account, with Delegation on:

[image]

Furthermore, as shown here, that client does have the permissions I need:

[image]

So I am stumped and would appreciate help.

My code is below, based on https://developers.google.com/+/domains/quickstart/python

```
# Update SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_FILE_PATH with the file path to the private key
# file downloaded from the developer console.
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_FILE_PATH = 'gsuite1-7b1dc64d67fd.json'
#SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_FILE_PATH = 'file.txt'

# Update USER_EMAIL with the email address of the user within your domain that
# you would like to act on behalf of.
USER_EMAIL = 'jschull@e-nable.org'


# plus.me and plus.stream.write are the scopes required to perform the tasks in
# this quickstart. For a full list of available scopes and their uses, please
# see the documentation.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write']


def authenticate():
  """Build and return a Plus service object authorized with the service accounts
  that act on behalf of the given user.

  Returns:
    Plus service object.
  """

  print( 'Authenticate the domain for %s' % USER_EMAIL)

  # Make service account credentials
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_FILE_PATH, scopes=SCOPES)

  # Setting the sub field with USER_EMAIL allows you to make API calls using the
  # special keyword 'me' in place of a user id for that user.
  delegate_credentials = credentials.create_delegated(USER_EMAIL)

  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = delegate_credentials.authorize(http)

  # Create and return the Plus service object
  return build('plusDomains', 'v1', http=http)
```

Comment: You have not implemented Domain Wide Delegation. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation. Note: Include your actual source code in the question and not screenshots of your code.

Comment: Thanks.  I added the code.  I think (thought?) the middle diagram demonstrates that domain wide delegation IS enabled.

Comment: The error message means that you have not implemented Domain Wide Delegation (this of course includes "incorrectly"). Go back thru the link, step-by-step. Tips. Make sure that `jschull` is a G Suite superadmin that has logged in and accepted the Google Terms & Conditions. Make sure that the service account `gsuite1-7b1dc64d67fd.json` is a new service account with no changes (blank service account). Your code looks correct.

Comment: There is a different in my code versus your code:

`credentials = credentials.with_subject(USER_EMAIL)`

 `service = build('plusDomains', 'v1', credentials=credentials)`